# PHP Using an Object from an included file in another included file

Tags: php, class, object, include

I will be straight to the point with this. Can't seem to find it anywhere on the internet. Maybe it is not even possible, i dont know. I do really like to use the method "divide and rule", created it myself. Splitting as much files as possible for easy management (small files and such).

But here is my problem:

I have 5 files:

```
index.php
inc/config.php
inc/Database.class.php
inc/sidebar.php
inc/forms.php
```

Okay, what i have done is this:

in my config.php file i included the Database.class.php file and created an object.

```
include 'Database.class.php';

$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$host = "localhost";
$database = "blah blah";

$db = new Database($user, $pass, $host, $database);
$db->connect();
```

So i included this config.php and sidebar.php in my index.php file.

(shortened the code, but it functions the same)

```
include 'inc/config.php';
include 'inc/sidebar.php';
```

In my sidebar i have a form, for users to login.

in sidebar.php i just include forms.php, this is the forms.php:
(I used print_r to debug my file, to see if anything returns and i left out the method loginFormShow because it is very long and not relevant)

```
function loginFormProcess($user, $pass)
{
    $db->select(blah blah some variables);
    $res = $db->getResult();
    print_r($res); 
}


if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    loginFormShow();
} else {

    if ($_POST['user'] == "") 
    {
        loginFormShow(1);
    } 
    else if ($_POST['pass'] == "") 
    {
        loginFormShow(2);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        loginFormProcess($user, $pass);
    }
}
```

And thus, what the problem is. When i try to call the function loginFormProcess, it cant use the object $db.

Can i use 1 object for this? Because on the index page i am going to require some other data from the database. Do i need to create an object for the index page and one for the login form?

Is there any other solution?
If i am not clear, i would love to give some more explanation.

Cheers,

Clemenz

Comment: Scope rules still apply to the $db variable, even though it's an object rather than a simple scalar... just because it's an object, doesn't make it global -  so it isn't in scope in your loginFormProcess() function

Comment: And how do i get it in the right scope without creating another object. I just want to use one object for multiple functions. Is this do-able?

Comment: you pass it as an argument to the loginFormProcess() function, exactly as Madara's answer shows, exactly as you'd pass any other variable to a function

Comment: Netbeans gives me an error whilst doing that. Do i need to include my database.class.php in forms? Or do i neet to pass $db to sidebar.php first and then to forms.php.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to pass the database object to the function's arguments as follows:

```
function loginFormProcess($user, $pass, Database $db) {
```

And call it with an appropriate Database object. This is what know as **[dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection)**.

Comment: But i declared $db in config.php not in database.class.php. So if i try this in netbeans, it gives me an error. So i try to use this:
`function loginFormProcess($user, $pass, Database::$db) {`

Not working either: `Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in something\inc\loginform.php on line 111`

Comment: @Clemenz: In that case, an [tag:autoloader] is in order.

Comment: @Clemenz: And no, I didn't say `Database::$db`, I said `Database $db`. It's called type-hinting.

Comment: i know you said Database $db, but that didnt work. But that didnt work and netbeans wanted me to type it with :: but that didn't work either. So there is no simple solution for this? Autoloader is not that simple. Then i will create multiple objects. Thanks alot for the effort!

Comment: @Clemenz: Autoloader is very simple. Why can't you use an autoloader? http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: Tried to use it, still cant get it to work. But its another problem now. Nothing relevant to this. Autoloader does its work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function loginFormProcess($user, $pass)
{
    global $db;
    $db->select(blah blah some variables);
    $res = $db->getResult();
    print_r($res); 
}
```

For reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Three answers all propogating bad practises.... PASS $db AS AN ARGUMENT, don't use global as the universal panacea

Comment: And how should i pass this? It is declared in config.php, included in index.php. And forms.php (where i use $db) is included in sidebar.php included in index.php. Damn, i include alot.

Comment: For my solution you can just add global $db in your sidebar.php file. But the other commenters are correct. This solution is nothing more than a quick but dirty hack. Try to study object oriented design principles. It'll save you time in the long run. A good book is 'Head First object-oriented analysis and design'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `$db` as **global**.

Try this:

```
function loginFormProcess($user, $pass)
{
    global $db;
    $db->select(blah blah some variables);
    $res = $db->getResult();
    print_r($res); 
}
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

The variable $db is created as a global variable in your config.php file.  This is invisible from inside the loginFormProcess function.  A shotcut solution you can use is declaring your intention of using a global variable by adding the statement global $db; as the first statement inside your function